# detect tabpage which is not selected but clicked C# windows form application

Tags: c#, windows, forms, tabcontrol

I am trying to build a web browser in Windows form application.I added an option of closing the tab in the contextmenu. I don't want the tabpage to be selected on right click, just the context menu needs to appear. That works fine. The problem is when I click close tab the previous tab is closed and not the current one as previous tab is the one which was selected. I tried to figure this out by getting the rectangle location of the tabpage but that appears to be the same for all the tabs. Please help!

```
    //this is my event handler for closing the tab
    private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tabControlBrowser.TabPages.Remove(this.tabControlBrowser.SelectedTab);   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yest you are correct that is because you are using

```
this.tabControlBrowser.TabPages.Remove(this.tabControlBrowser.SelectedTab);
```

this will remove the current selected tab but not the tab page that you are clicking on.

Please try below code hope it will help you to move forward

```
TabPage _ClickedTab;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.tabControl1.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(tabControl1_MouseClick);

    }

    void tabControl1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            this.contextMenuStrip1.Show(this.tabControl1, e.Location);


            Rectangle r2 = this.tabControl1.GetTabRect(0);

            foreach (TabPage item in this.tabControl1.TabPages)
            {
                Rectangle r = this.tabControl1.GetTabRect(tabControl1.TabPages.IndexOf(item));
                if (r.X < e.Location.X && e.Location.X < r.X + r.Width && r.Y < e.Location.Y && e.Location.Y < r.Y + r.Height)
                {
                    _ClickedTab = item;
                }

            }


        }
    }


    private void toolStripMenuItem3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(_ClickedTab);
    }
```

Comment: But this event handler doesn't get called when context menu appears. When I right click on a tab the selected index doesn't get changed until I left click it. I don't want the tab to be selected on right click.

Comment: saved me hours of trial and error. Love StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You could test the location of the mouse against the rectangles returned by TabControl#GetTabRect